# HowTo exclude signature from XML signed file?

Tags: c++, signature, msxml5

I used **DSign** methods from **MSXML 5.0** dll (IDE - *MSVC*) to be able `sign()` and `verify()` XML documents, but just for now I need to find methods, to exclude signature fields from signed XML file.

I have tried to find the solution on the Internet, but no luck.

Have any one faced with this problem and solved it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the signature elements? They have their own namespace URI, even: `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig`